# Using IndexSlice to filter MultiIndex Dataframes with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, slice, nan, multi-index

**Question:** How do I filter the rows such that I return only the rows where the injection is not equal to 0 or NaN and not lose the values of the other columns?

I have a dataframe created with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(
               [
               [5777, 100, 5385, 200, 5419, 4887, 100, 200],
               [4849, 0, 4539, 0, 3381, 0, 0, ],
               [4971, 0, 3824, 0, 4645, 3424, 0, 0, ],
               [4827, 200, 3459, 300, 4552, 3153, 100, 200, ],
               [5207, 0, 3670, 0, 4876, 3358, 0, 0, ],
               ],
               index=pd.to_datetime(['2010-01-01',
                                     '2010-01-02',
                                     '2010-01-03',
                                     '2010-01-04',
                                     '2010-01-05']),
               columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                                                [('Portfolio A', 'GBP', 'amount'),
                                                 ('Portfolio A', 'GBP', 'injection'),
                                                 ('Portfolio B', 'EUR', 'amount'),                                           ('Portfolio B', 'EUR', 'injection'),
                                                 ('Portfolio C', 'USD', 'amount'),                                           ('Portfolio C', 'USD', 'injection'),
                                                 ('Portfolio D', 'JPY', 'amount'),                                           ('Portfolio D', 'JPY', 'injection')])
                                   ).sortlevel(axis=1)
```

**Next I can create a DataFrame with the slice of the data (in this instance it's all the data)**

```
df1=df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:], pd.IndexSlice[:,:, ['amount', 'injection']]]
```

**Next create a new DataFrame where injection is != 0**

```
df2=df1[df1.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:], pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'injection']]!=0]
```

**Question:** Why does this reset all values in 'amount' column to NaN?

The next step once the amounts are available is to remove rows with all NaN

```
df3=df2.dropna(axis=0, how='all', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
```

**The desired output is all data across row indexes:**

```
2010-01-01
2010-01-03
2010-01-04
2010-01-05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True` values if need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) which works with mask as `boolean Series`:

```
print (df1.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'injection']].fillna(0) != 0)
           Portfolio A Portfolio B Portfolio C Portfolio D
                   GBP         EUR         USD         JPY
             injection   injection   injection   injection
2010-01-01        True        True        True        True
2010-01-02       False       False       False       False
2010-01-03       False       False        True       False
2010-01-04        True        True        True        True
2010-01-05       False       False        True       False

mask = (df1.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'injection']].fillna(0) != 0).any(axis=1)
print (mask)
2010-01-01     True
2010-01-02    False
2010-01-03     True
2010-01-04     True
2010-01-05     True
dtype: bool

print (df1[mask])
           Portfolio A           Portfolio B           Portfolio C            \
                   GBP                   EUR                   USD             
                amount injection      amount injection      amount injection   
2010-01-01        5777       100        5385       200        5419      4887   
2010-01-03        4971         0        3824         0        4645      3424   
2010-01-04        4827       200        3459       300        4552      3153   
2010-01-05        5207         0        3670         0        4876      3358   

           Portfolio D            
                   JPY            
                amount injection  
2010-01-01         100     200.0  
2010-01-03           0       0.0  
2010-01-04         100     200.0  
2010-01-05           0       0.0
```

If use mask as `boolean DataFrame` get `NaN` where `False` values.

Comment: your answer is missing the data from '2010-01-03' and '2010-01-05' for 'Portfolio C'

Comment: Sorry, what is desired output? Filter rows with all values not equal `0` or filter at least by one not equal `0` value?

Comment: Desired output is to exclude any row for a given date that has all values not equal `0`, I think there is a need to replace the `NaNs` with zero first also.

Comment: Sorry, desired output is to exclude any row for a given date that has all 'injection' values equal `0`, I also think there is a need to replace the `NaNs` with zero first.

Comment: I edit answer - also add `fillna(0)`, what add one `False` value to boolean mask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126738/discussion-between-toasteez-and-jezrael).

Comment: I think an edit to this fixes it: `mask = (df1.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'injection']].fillna(0) !=0).any(axis=1)`